# How do I enable the SOAP module for PHP?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, osx-leopard

How I enable PHP Soap module on my Mac OSX 10.5.8?

PHP is already installed but Soap module isn't configured when I've installed apache / php / mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link

http://web.archive.org/web/20150223153105/http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2008/12/17/installing-php-soap-extension-on-leopard-10-5-5

seems to be just about your issue.

I copy the link here:

> While working a new project of mine, SoapSource: a soap datasource for
>   Cakephp, I wanted to make use of PHP’s SOAP extension. As I figured
>   out quickly the default install of PHP on Mac OS X Leopard isn’t
>   compiled with the SOAP extension enabled. So I thought; that’s easy,
>   just recompile PHP with the SOAP extension enabled.. However I
>   encountered some serious problems. It appears to be impossible to
>   compile a 64bit version of PHP on Mac OS, there’s some sort of bug
>   with ‘libiconv’. So next idea, recompile Apache in 32bit, Mysql in
>   32bit and ofcourse PHP in 32bit… well again I didn’t succeed, so I
>   reverted all my changes back to the original settings after a day of
>   hard work and frustrations.
>
> But then I found out you can compile dynamic extensions without
>   recompiling your entire PHP installation. So I got SOAP running within
>   5 minutes using to following instructions:
>
> Download the PHP source of the version your Mac is running, probably
>   PHP-5.2.6, and extract the package.
>
> cd /tmp
>
> curl -O http://de3.php.net/distributions/php-5.2.6.tar.bz2
>
> tar xjf php-5.2.6.tar.bz2
>
> Then move to the expanded directory and execute the following
>   commands.
>
> cd php-5.2.6/
>
> export LIBTOOLIZE=glibtoolize MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
>
> cd ext/soap
>
> phpize
>
> Now we need to compile and install the extension.
>
> MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 CFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
>   -no-cpp-precomp" CCFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe" CXXFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe" LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -bind_at_load" ./configure
>
> make
>
> sudo make install
>
> Now the extension has been compiled and installed,
>   but you’ll probably need to do some more configuration before it will
>   work.
>
> Edit your php.ini, which is located in /private/etc/php.ini
>
> Change the ‘extension_dir’ to ‘/usr/lib/php/extensions’ and enable the extension
>   by adding this line ‘extension=soap.so’
>
> Create a symbolic link to the soap extension
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/soap.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/soap.so
>
> And finally restart apache for the changes to take effect
>
> sudo apachectl restart
>
> That’s it! you can now use the SOAP extensions.
>   Please let me know if you have any comments or problems with this.

Comment: Please don´t answer with external links since they often gets broken. Like it is in just case...

Comment: You can still find it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20150223153105/http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2008/12/17/installing-php-soap-extension-on-leopard-10-5-5